# LinearLayout not declaring

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm having trouble with the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <string name= "title_activity_driver_map" >Map</string></LinearLayout>
```

The LinearLayout is not declaring. I'm not sure why I've used the tag Linear Layout elsewhere on my project and it works fine with the same 1st line of code.

Would appreciate any help :)

Comment: What do you want to see? You can add views to `LinearLayout`, not strings.

Comment: The code line `<string name= "title_activity_driver_map" >Map</string>` is not valid here. Cut it from here and paste it in file *res/values/strings.xml*

Comment: what do you want to achieve you can add views not string file in main layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want like this below -

add required height and width to `LinearLayout` this is important for container and put `TextView` inside Layout to show the string value, move `<string name= "title_activity_driver_map" >Map</string>` inside `res/values/strings.xml`  and give reference in layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/title_activity_driver_map"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want show a tex in layout but use incorrect way.
in android at first you should declare layout like linear,relative ,...
and in body of layout you can put all thing such as button ,textview,edittext,...
in your case you can use linearlayout and in body of layout put textview and set the text of text of it **map** as you want like this.
if you want to have better code you can put the text in  stringMap in values folders strings.xml file. res>values>strins.xml
like the code below.

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">app_name</string>
    <string name= "title_activity_driver_map" >Map</string>
</resources>
```

and after that you can set the text in textview that you declare in layout like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/title_activity_driver_map"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

good luck

Answer (score 0):

Put your string`<string name= "title_activity_driver_map" >Map</string>` in `values` folders `strings.xml` file.
**res>values>strins.xml**

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">app_name</string>
    <string name= "title_activity_driver_map" >Map</string>
</resources>
```

Then declare this string in your layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/title_activity_driver_map"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```